# How to customize appearance of UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I want to customize the search bar, I mean the white box. Can I do it?
Is there some documentation about that?
Is there a way to hide the white box, but not the letters.
Can I at least make the box smaller? I mean less height

Answer (score 57, accepted):

By IOS 5.0 you have the chance to use

```
  [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can we change it's height ?

Comment: Assign a background image with your desired height it should change it

Comment: Thanks @Ilker Baltaci , already tried it stays at original height

Comment: Did you also change the frame of the search bar ?

Answer (score 27):

Here is the solution I was looking for:
Subclassing a UISearchBar, & overwriting the method layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   UITextField *searchField;
   NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
   for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
      if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
      }
   }
   if(!(searchField == nil)) {
       searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"buscador.png"] ];
       [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
   }

   [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: @Jhaliya, Where should I put this part of code to get custom background for searchbar?

Answer (score 24):

Here is some common properties you can change to customize UISearchBar:
[image]

Answer (score 16):

```
// Search Bar Customization
// Background Image
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];

// Backgroud Color
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

// Search Bar Cancel Button Color
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// set Search Bar Search icon
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_ico.png"]
                                forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
                                           state:UIControlStateNormal];

// set Search Bar textfield background image
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_box.png"]
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set Search Bar texfield corder radius
UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.8f;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could change the background of `UISearchBar`

[Customize a UISearchBar background](http://forrst.com/posts/Customize_a_UISearchBar_background-7UD)

[How to Control UISearchBar Background Color](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-control-uisearchbar-background.html)

Comment: Here is the solution I was looking for:

Answer (score 2):

> Some examples in Swift

```
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()])
        UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

  UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "searchBarSearchIcon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
        UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

There're few attempts out there including subclass UISearchBar and hack it's `layoutSubviews` or `drawLayer:`. After iOS 5, the best method is to use UIAppearance.

```
// Configure your images
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar"];
UIImage *searchFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchfield"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

// Set it to your UISearchBar appearance
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchFieldImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

**use the below code to transparent your searchbar**

```
// Set it to your UISearchBar appearance

[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchFieldImage 
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

(UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]) ).defaultTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

Comment: please give us more details about this answer!