# How can I create a custom UISearchBar

Tags: ios, searchbar

In iOS there is a search bar component with text field.
How can I customize the text field to something else? with different image ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to customize apperance of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201406/how-to-custom-uisearchbar)

http://forrst.com/posts/Customize_a_UISearchBar_background-7UD

http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-control-uisearchbar-background.html

If you are expecting a sample code this is not an ideal website for you =)

Happy Coding