# remove the border of uitextfield in uisearchbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I wanna custom the UISearchBar control to a style as showed in the picture below:
[image: It's a customed UISearchBar, there is no boarder for the textfield here.]

First I should remove the background view, then  find out the UITextfiled in UISearchBar,  extend the frame of UITextfiled and remove the boarder of it.

Here is my code :

```
UITextField *searchField;

NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
for(int i = 0; i != numViews; i++) {
    if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
if(!(searchField == nil)) {

    [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    searchField.frame = self.frame; //modify the frame
}

[[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0]removeFromSuperview]; //remove the background.
```

The result is the boarder of the UITextField is still there. :(

[image]

My question is :
1.Why can not I modify the appearance of the UITextField of UISearchBar?

2.How to remove the boarder of UITextfield in UISearchBar.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass UISearchBar and override layoutSubViews to remove the search bar background and the text field border subviews:

```c
- (void)layoutSubviews
{    
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        // Remove the default background
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        // Remove the rounded corners
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
            for (UIView *subsubview in textField.subviews) {
               if ([subsubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextFieldBorderView")]) {
                    [subsubview removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to subclass, put this where you /lazy/ load your UISearchBar:
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ /*MAGIC HERE*/ });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about this, however I suspect the only way you're going to be able to achieve a `UISearchBar` like that of the one in your image is to create a new subclass of `UISearchBar`. Using that you could set it up to look exactly like the one in your image.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201406/how-to-custom-uisearchbar) may be of some help to you if you decide to go down the route of subclassing.

Comment: The subclass way doesn't work. Thank you all the same, I think I have to create my own SearchBar, I don't know if it's a good way. Still I don't understand why I can not modify the appearance of the UITextField as I want. Whatever, Thanks all the same.

Comment: biaobiaoqi, did you ever find a way to do this? I need to do something like this myself