# What is the proper way to change UISearchBar background to custom image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I know people asked this before and I found this solution:

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
        bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"]];
        [searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure if it include some private API that apple will reject, or is there a better way to do this?

- I'm still supporting ios 4, so no ios 5 only APIs

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to custom UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201406/how-to-custom-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not encourage people who are using private undocumented apis.

But still you can use subclassing feature in your application. I have used this kind of subclassing UISearchBarBackground. Apple was accepted my application which was in live. So no issues of using above code in your application.

Comment: Do u know a better way to do so?

Comment: I guess only the better way are available in IOS 5. I don't remember currently.